# Getting only the last value from db multiple times in listview

Tags: java, android, android-volley

am presently using volley and am trying to receive a foreach result from my php and send it to my list view. problem am getting is that i keep recieving the the last value 4 times where as there are only two values in the db. also only the last value among this two is shown and it is shown 4 times

i have tried using jsonObject and jsonArray, i dont know what am doing wrong

```
private void loadList() {
    displayLoader();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    try {
        //Populate the request parameters

        request.put(KEY_USER, userID);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, login_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            Log.e ( "response", "" + response);
                            //JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            ModelTestData test = new ModelTestData(response.getString("research")
                                    ,response.getString("name")
                                    ,response.getString("hospital")
                                    ,response.getString("type"));

                            test.setResearch(response.getString("research"));
                            test.setName(response.getString("name"));
                            test.setHospital(response.getString("hospital"));
                            test.setType(response.getString("type"));


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            testList.add(test);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Olau", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    //      "Finally success second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
}
```

This is what the response looks like

```
{"research":"I got this error while debugging an android app on Android Studio via USB. Connection attempts failed with one tablet but not with my regular test tablet. It turned out that the failure was due to the fact that I hadn't enabled WIFI settings on the failing machine. So I enabled WIFI on it and it connected to server OK.","name":"Pestal feel","hospital":"Saint Paule","type":"Pancrease","0":true}{"research":"I got this error while debugging an android app on Android Studio via USB. Connection attempts failed with one tablet but not with my regular test tablet. It turned out that the failure was due to the fact that I hadn't enabled WIFI settings on the failing machine. So I enabled WIFI on it and it connected to server OK.","name":"Coner stone","hospital":"Saint Paule","type":"Breast","0":true,"1":true}
```

Comment: Can you share complete json. The response you shared is incomplete it only has 2 json objects and are not comma separated. Are they a part of JSON Array?

Comment: what I posted is the value am getting from my php. thats the complete value @User

Comment: Its an invalid json. Try validating your json first Use this tool to check if its valid or not
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: I guess these json objects are supposed to be inside a JSON array so your parsing will work like this 
ModelTestData test=new ModelTestData();
test.setResearch(response.getJSONArray("yourarrayname").getJSONObject(i).getString("research"));

Comment: made a mistake in my php just rectified it